# How to test whether useState has been called or a button has been clicked?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I've been trying to find a way to get 100% coverage on a simple `tsx` file and the only two lines that jest tells me need coverage are where I pass a callback that execute a `setState` from `useState`.

I've read that I shouldn't test hooks since user only cares about the UI. That's why my question goes as to how to get those two lines tested.

```
function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [step, setStep] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <main className={style.app}>
      <Grid className={style.header} centerAlign>
        <button
          id="home-button"
          className={style.headerHomeBtn}
          onClick={() => setStep(0)}
        >
          <img className={style.headerHome} src={home} alt="home button" />
        </button>
        <h1>Financial Advisor</h1>
      </Grid>
      {step === 0 && <RiskSelector continue={() => setStep(1)} />}
      {step === 1 && <Portfolio />}
    </main>
  );
}
```

`Uncovered line #s: 18-24`

Which are the `onClick` and `continue` props. And my test so far is:

```
describe('Dummy', () => {
  let wrapper: any;
  const setState = jest.fn();
  const useStateMock: any = (initState: any) => [initState, setState];

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Dummy />);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  describe('Home button clicked', () => {
    it('calls setStep with 0', () => {
      jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockImplementation(useStateMock);
      console.log(wrapper.debug());
      wrapper.find('button').props().onClick();
      expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

The console output just shows me that the button is there.

The test doesn't pass because `setState` was never called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should NOT mock `React.useState()` hook, and test the implementation details of the event handler. You should test the behavior of the component. The behavior is, for example, when the state changes, what happens to the view.

E.g.

`App.tsx`:

```
import { Grid } from './Grid';
import React from 'react';
import { RiskSelector } from './RiskSelector';
import { Portfolio } from './Portfolio';

const home = 'http://localhost:3000/home.png';

export function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [step, setStep] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <main>
      <Grid centerAlign>
        <button id="home-button" onClick={() => setStep(0)}>
          <img src={home} alt="home button" />
        </button>
        <h1>Financial Advisor</h1>
      </Grid>
      {step === 0 && <RiskSelector continue={() => setStep(1)} />}
      {step === 1 && <Portfolio />}
    </main>
  );
}
```

`Grid.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export function Grid({ children, centerAlign }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

`Portfolio.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
export function Portfolio() {
  return <div>Portfolio</div>;
}
```

`RiskSelector.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export function RiskSelector({ continue: onContinue }) {
  return <div onClick={onContinue}></div>;
}
```

`App.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { App } from './App';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Portfolio } from './Portfolio';
import { RiskSelector } from './RiskSelector';

describe('67412919', () => {
  let wrapper: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  describe('Home button clicked', () => {
    it('calls setStep with 0', () => {
      wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
      expect(wrapper.find(RiskSelector)).toHaveLength(1);
    });

    it('calls setStep with 1', () => {
      wrapper.find(RiskSelector).invoke('continue')();
      expect(wrapper.find(Portfolio)).toHaveLength(1);
      expect(wrapper.find(RiskSelector)).toHaveLength(0);
    });
  });
});
```

unit test result with 100% coverage for `App.tsx` file.

```
 PASS  examples/67412919/App.test.tsx (7.433 s)
  67412919
    Home button clicked
      ✓ calls setStep with 0 (24 ms)
      ✓ calls setStep with 1 (12 ms)

------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File              | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files         |   84.21 |      100 |      50 |   84.21 |                   
 App.tsx          |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 Grid.tsx         |   66.67 |      100 |       0 |   66.67 | 4                 
 Portfolio.tsx    |   66.67 |      100 |       0 |   66.67 | 3                 
 RiskSelector.tsx |   66.67 |      100 |       0 |   66.67 | 4                 
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.958 s, estimated 8 s
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that only the user only cares about UI, the tests for functional components also care solely about the UI :). In other words, test the changing rendered content, not the implementation of a function.

So, simulate that button click and test whether `RiskSelector` or `Portfolio` is rendered.

Comment: That's how I would do it too. Although i'm not sure what the coverage reporter would say about that.

Comment: I'd guess it would be covered, but to be sure, one can always wrap this `setStep` in some other function...